# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express for a single website?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Someone recently told me I could use SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition for a single website. But don't you need the Server Agent for connections (I think. I'm trying to remember things from over several years ago now!) and Express has it's Server Agent disabled?

Comment: How would you use the server if you couldn't connect to it?

Comment: SQL Express actually doesn't have the agent at all any more.  The service isn't even registered on the server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need the SQL Server Agent. It has nothing to do with database connectivity.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx

> SQL Server Agent is a Microsoft
>   Windows service that executes
>   scheduled administrative tasks, which
>   are called jobs. SQL Server Agent uses
>   SQL Server to store job information.
>   Jobs contain one or more job steps.
>   Each step contains its own task, for
>   example, backing up a database. SQL
>   Server Agent can run a job on a
>   schedule, in response to a specific
>   event, or on demand. For example, if
>   you want to back up all the company
>   servers every weekday after hours, you
>   can automate this task. Schedule the
>   backup to run after 22:00 Monday
>   through Friday; if the backup
>   encounters a problem, SQL Server Agent
>   can record the event and notify you.

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question I just remember once (a long time ago) trying to setup SQL Express, being unsuccessful and everything at the time said it was because of the lack of server agent. Am I thinking of some other reason for this?

Comment: The setup process for SQL Server 2005 Express somewhat fragile. Newer versions are more robust. You should install SQL Server Express and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay maybe I'm looking for a problem that doesn't really exist. I just had a really strong feeling about it.

Comment: One downside of no agent is you'll need some other mechanism to schedule backups, the Windows task scheduler works fine.

Comment: Well I'll be damned, it actually worked perfectly. I would have sworn it wouldn't have. Any way thanks again for you time!